# How do I add the elements of an array to another array

Tags: ruby

I recently ran into the problem of trying to assign the contents of one array to another array, my current solution is:

```
 first_array.each do |x|
   second_array << x
 end
```

Comment: The correct answer depends on what you actually mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `dup` (duplicate) method:

```
second_array = first_array.dup
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array1 += array2
```

If there's already stuff in the first one.